# Virtual Host in Apache downloads the file instead of displaying it

Tags: .net, linux, apache, mono

I'm using apache2 w/ mono mod and it works fine when I go to my local ip.
192.168.1.210

but when I try to go to my virtual host

www.example.com

It will download the webpage instead of displaying it.
File: mod_mono.conf

```
  GNU nano 2.2.6                                                                                                          

AddType application/x-asp-net .aspx .ashx .asmx .ascx .asax .config .ascx
DirectoryIndex index.aspx

# Include the web application definitions generated by mono-server{2,4}-update.
#
# If you want to use ASP.NET 2.0 (via mono-apache-server2), use:
# Include /etc/mono-server2/mono-server2-hosts.conf
#
# If you want to use ASP.NET 4.0 (via mono-apache-server4), use:
# Include /etc/mono-server4/mono-server4-hosts.conf

Include /etc/mono-server4/mono-server4-hosts.conf


<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  ServerAdmin web-admin@example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  # MonoServerPath can be changed to specify which version of ASP.NET is hosted
  # mod-mono-server1 = ASP.NET 1.1 / mod-mono-server2 = ASP.NET 2.0
  # For SUSE Linux Enterprise Mono Extension, uncomment the line below:
  # MonoServerPath example.com "/opt/novell/mono/bin/mod-mono-server4"
  # For Mono on openSUSE, uncomment the line below instead:
  MonoServerPath example.com "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"

  # To obtain line numbers in stack traces you need to do two things:
  # 1) Enable Debug code generation in your page by using the Debug="true"
  #    page directive, or by setting <compilation debug="true" /> in the
  #    application's Web.config
  # 2) Uncomment the MonoDebug true directive below to enable mod_mono debugging
  #MonoDebug example.com true

  # The MONO_IOMAP environment variable can be configured to provide platform abstraction
  # for file access in Linux.  Valid values for MONO_IOMAP are:
  #    case
  #    drive
  #    all
  # Uncomment the line below to alter file access behavior for the configured application
  MonoSetEnv example.com MONO_IOMAP=all
  #
  # Additional environtment variables can be set for this server instance using
  # the MonoSetEnv directive.  MonoSetEnv takes a string of 'name=value' pairs
  # separated by semicolons.  For instance, to enable platform abstraction *and*
  # use Mono's old regular expression interpreter (which is slower, but has a
  # shorter setup time), uncomment the line below instead:
  # MonoSetEnv example.com MONO_IOMAP=all;MONO_OLD_RX=1

  MonoApplications example.com "/:/var/www/html"
  <Location "/">
    Allow from all
    Order allow,deny
    MonoSetServerAlias example.com
    SetHandler mono
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
  </Location>
  <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

apache.conf

```
  GNU nano 2.2.6                                                                                                           File: apache2.conf

# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#       /etc/apache2/
#       |-- apache2.conf
#       |       `--  ports.conf
#       |-- mods-enabled
#       |       |-- *.load
#       |       `-- *.conf
#       |-- conf-enabled
#       |       `-- *.conf
#       `-- sites-enabled
#               `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.

# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
```

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @Reinaldo Unfortunately not. I gave up trying to use mono mod and ended up using PHP instead due to a few issues, this being one of them.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to solve it by using the autoconfiguration feature http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono-autoconfiguration/